# Сумма чисел через string в консоле

Tags: c++, консоль

Нужно что бы после написания в консоль

```
15+5+30
```

выводилось

```
50
```

Какой алгоритм выполнения данного задания? Неудачный кусок кода ниже.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    cout << "Enter expression:\n";
    string s, s1;
    int n, sum = 0, h;
    getline(cin, s);
    h = s.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == '+') {
            s1=s.substr(0, i - 1);
            n = atoi(s.c_str());
            s = s.erase(0, i+1);
            sum += n;                       
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дебаггером пользоваться пробовали? Во-первых у вас `.substr` берет на один символ меньше, чем нужно. А во-вторых, когда вы делаете `.erase`, размер строки меняется. А вы этого никак не учитываете, и в итоге обращаетесь за границы строки.

Comment: Дебагером пользовался и даже понял в чем проблема, цикл после преобразования первого числа завершается из-за того что размер строки уменьшается. `.substr` берет на один символ меньше для того что бы не учитывать знак `+` (для atoi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного изменил ваш код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter expression:\n";
    string expr;
    int sum = 0;
    getline(cin, expr);
    expr += '+'; // Если этого не сделать - то нужно будет добавить дополнительную проверку последние ли это число 
    while(expr.size())
    {
        sum += stoi(std::string(expr.begin(), expr.begin() + expr.find('+')));
        expr.erase(expr.begin(), expr.begin() + expr.find('+') + 1);
    }
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Имеет смысл записать `expr.begin() + expr.find('+')` в переменную, чтобы не искать дважды.

Comment: Имеет, но думаю что так более наглядно